# how can i reuse the same modal in ionic?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic6

sorry about the title I wasn't sure how to phrase this question, But my issue is that I have a list of clickable elements and I want to pass their data to a single modal instead of creating modals for each list element? so for example i click on item 1 and its data is displayed inside the modal, after i close the modal i click on item 2 and its data is displayed using the same modal. I looked through the ionic docs but I couldn't find anything similar to this there, I tried changing the id that the modal uses to trigger it opening to a class but that didn't work, would anyone have any pointers for my issue?

thanks in advance!

list-details.component.html

```
<ion-list>
     <ng-container *ngFor="let item of myList">
      <ion-item detail="true">
        <ion-button id="open-modal" expand="block" (click)="getItem(item)">
          <ion-label>
            <h2 class="headline">{{item.beer}}</h2>
            <h3 class="sub-headline">{{item.name}}</h3>
            <p>{{item.notes}}</p>
            <p>{{item.price | currency}}</p>
            <app-rating [rating]="item.rating"></app-rating>
          </ion-label>
        </ion-button>
      </ion-item>
      </ng-container>
    </ion-list>
    
    <ion-modal trigger="open-modal" (willDismiss)="onWillDismiss($event)">
      <ng-template>
        <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar>
            <ion-buttons slot="start">
              <ion-button (click)="cancel()">Cancel</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
            <ion-title>{{user.name}}</ion-title>
            <ion-buttons slot="end">
              <ion-button (click)="confirm()" [strong]="true">Confirm</ion-button>
            </ion-buttons>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header>
        <ion-content class="ion-padding">
          <ion-item>
            <ion-label position="stacked">Enter your name</ion-label>
            <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Your name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-content>
      </ng-template>
    </ion-modal>
```

list-details.component.ts

```
    export class ListDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild(IonModal) modal: IonModal;
  
  message = 'This modal example uses triggers to automatically open a modal when the button is clicked.';
  name: string;
  user: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  

  getItem(item: any){
    this.user = item;
  }
  cancel() {
    this.modal.dismiss(null, 'cancel');
  }

  confirm() {
    this.modal.dismiss(this.name, 'confirm');
  }

  onWillDismiss(event: Event) {
    const ev = event as CustomEvent<OverlayEventDetail<string>>;
    if (ev.detail.role === 'confirm') {
      this.message = `Hello, ${ev.detail.data}!`;
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> With the modalController developers can present an ion-modal
> programmatically. Developers will have complete control over when a
> modal is presented and dismissed.

> **app.component.html**

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-content>
    <hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
    <p>Dynamic Data with Ionic Modal Example</p>

    <ng-container *ngFor="let data of listData">
      <ion-item href="#" (click)="openIonModal(data)">
        <ion-label>{{ data.name }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>
    </ng-container>
  </ion-content>
</ion-app>
```

> **app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, VERSION } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { CustomModalComponent } from '../custom-modal/custom-modal.component';

export interface ListData {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = 'Ionic 6.2 Angular ' + VERSION.major;

  listData: ListData[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Test 1',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Test 2',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Test 3',
    },
  ];

  modelData: any;

  constructor(private _modalController: ModalController) {}

  ionViewDidEnter() {}

  async openIonModal(data: ListData) {
    const modal = await this._modalController.create({
      component: CustomModalComponent,
      componentProps: {
        modelTitle: data.name,
      },
    });
    modal.onDidDismiss().then((modelData) => {
      if (modelData !== null) {
        this.modelData = modelData.data;
        console.log('Modal Data : ' + modelData.data);
      }
    });
    return await modal.present();
  }
}
```

> **custom-modal.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-modal',
  templateUrl: './custom-modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-modal.component.css'],
})
export class CustomModalComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() modelTitle: string;

  constructor(private _modalController: ModalController) {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  async closeModel() {
    const close: string = 'Modal Removed';
    await this._modalController.dismiss(close);
  }
}
```

> **custom-modal.component.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>Ionic Modal Popup Example</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center> Model Title : {{ modelTitle }} </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col text-center>
        <ion-button (click)="closeModel()">Close</ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

[Working example is here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic6-angular13-wnmgmu?file=src/custom-modal/custom-modal.component.html)

Comment: Ionic recommends the use of in-line modals.  Your answer is how I would do it prior to the in-line modals.  I am having quite a bit of trouble trying to reuse in-line modals when it comes to custom styling. As the ion-modal has to be in the parent. This means I have to style the ion-modal part in the parent and can't just have it standalone in the modal component itself.